# Connecting Azure Data lake store from Presto DB: No FileSystem for scheme: adl

Tags: azure, jar, azure-data-lake, presto

I am trying the run a Presto DB on my local machine to connect the data from Azure Datalake store. Even after adding the JAR files for Azure Data lake store not able to fetch the data from Azure DataLake Store.

I get the below error:

```
Query 20181005_191247_00000_wcgur failed: No FileSystem for scheme: adl

    com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: No FileSystem for scheme: adl
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader$HiveSplitLoaderTask.process(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:189)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks.safeProcessTask(ResumableTasks.java:47)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks.access$000(ResumableTasks.java:20)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks$1.run(ResumableTasks.java:35)
    at io.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: adl
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.createFileSystem(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.getInternal(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.get(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.lambda$getFileSystem$0(HdfsEnvironment.java:71)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.authentication.NoHdfsAuthentication.doAs(NoHdfsAuthentication.java:23)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.getFileSystem(HdfsEnvironment.java:70)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.getFileSystem(HdfsEnvironment.java:64)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadPartition(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:282)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadSplits(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:256)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.access$300(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:91)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader$HiveSplitLoaderTask.process(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:185)
    ... 7 more
```

Reference:

Persto server: presto-server-0.212.tar.gz
Presto CLI: presto-cli-0.212-executable.jar

JARs added to plugin/hive-hadoop2:
hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.jar
azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.3.2.jar
hadoop-azure-3.1.1.jar

**hive.properties**

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hive:9083
hive.config.resources=presto/server/etc/catalog/adls-site.xml
```

**adls-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.adl.impl</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.adl.impl</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.Adl</value>
        </property>
        <property>
        <name>fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
        <value>ClientCredential</value>
        </property>

        <property>
        <name>fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
        <value>my_url</value>
        </property>

        <property>
        <name>fs.adl.oauth2.client.id</name>
        <value>my_id</value>
        </property>

        <property>
        <name>fs.adl.oauth2.credential</name>
        <value>my_cred</value>
        </property>

  </configuration>
```

Any comment on this will be much helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure this will be helpful, but Starburst provides ready to use (and free) solution for Azure: https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-azure/ (disclaimer: i'm from Starburst). I don't know the details though, so won't be able to help you replicate that on your local machine. I only recall it involves some important changes beyond plugging a jar.

Comment: @Piotr Thank you for the comment. Even though our total poc on presto was taken after starburst's announcement of presto on azure HDINSIGHT,  I wish to try this outside the Hdinsight. Not sure whether starburst's free distribution of presto will help there. Will try with that too and keep posted.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen . I tested it with Starburst on Azure HD Insight. Same issue exists there as well.

Comment: It's sad to hear that. I know it works in general (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-hdinsight-and-starburst-brings-presto-to-microsoft-azure-customers/), so it might be something specific to your configuration or environment. I'd recommend reaching out at https://www.starburstdata.com/contact/ with any relevant details (exact version you use, steps taken, etc.)